# Comment a remarkable point in a graphic

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a graphic like this one, based on dates/values:

[image]

Some points on the graphic represent special events, and I'd like to associate them with a comment, like: "Called the manager", "Strike", ... keeping the comment that shows the value if present.

I can add that comment in the table of values if needed.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Rob Bovey's XY Chart Labeler Add-in](http://appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) it *might* do what you want. Otherwise `insert - text box` will insert a text box you can move to the front and display it.

Unfortunately, there is no functionality currently to add *comment bubbles* to *points* on an excel *chart*, though that seems to be exactly what you want, right?

Comment: Right. Or a vertical bar with a comment at its top.